# Can I post an answer to a non-existing question?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

So I had a question, I did not find any solution to it. Then a while later I got a little creative and I fixed the issue.

So this is the question: can I post this solution to help others who might have problems with it in the future?

Comment: I quickly looked down if you answered this question. That would have been *meta*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may answer your own questions. The implication is that you also may ask a question solely for the purpose of answering it.